# Draw UIImage in Context with Perspective?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a UIImage which is a square. When drawing it in a context I do:

[image]

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.image!.size, imageView.opaque, 0.0)

//context
var drawCtxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
var someImage = UIImage(...)

// draw the image
CGContextDrawImage(drawCtxt, imageRect, someImage!.CGImage)
```

I want to draw the image in perspective like this:

[image]

**How can I draw a UIImage in a context in perspective?**